# How to let a user open a file stored on the server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I have a WordPress site, in which type1 users can upload *.doc files and type2 users should be able to open them by clicking on a link which represents a file.
The file then should be opened in a new window of the browser.

I got the first part easily - there are many guides on uploading a file.
But I couldn't find one that goes through all the steps of getting and opening a file which resides on a server directory.

I assume clicking the link should cause an ajax request which will send the file key to the server.
The server can then get from the MySQL DB the file name and location.

But what do I do then?
How do I get the file from the server directory, send it back to the client and open it for reading in the browser?

**Edit:**
I want the files to be confidential and not let just anyone read them so giving the users the link for the file on the server isn't the right way.
I still think I need to send the file from the server directory to the client.
How can this be done?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can't you just link to the uploaded file inside WP? I know for a fact that this is possible.

Comment: I didn't know modern browsers can read doc files... You usually need to download them and open them in MSWord.

Comment: @Pekka, I'd love to know how.

Comment: @Truth, I don't mind if it's downloaded automatically to a local temp directory and then opens Word also automatically.
But are you sure Word can't be opened inside a browser window?

Comment: Browsers can't open Word files natively. Microsoft Office includes a plugin that adds the functionality to some browsers. I make a point of disabling it on any system I use with MS Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the files to be confidential and not let just anyone read them so giving the users the link for the file on the server isn't the right way.

Yes it is. You can't let people read the document without giving them the document.

If you want to keep it confidential, then require the users to agree not to share the link with anyone else. Or go further and add a layer of authentication + authorisation and also require that users not hand over their credentials.

Comment: Well, users might agree to my conditions but the files will not be really protected as long as a simple URL opens them for anyone. Is there no way of sending a file to a user, as long as they request it?

Comment: How can the user request the file without a URI? That is the point of a URI, to identify the resource being requested.

Comment: Like this: The page has the key value to locate all the file's details in the DB and clicking the link (which isn't necessarily a link but can look like one) calls an `onClick` function which will use ajax to send the key value to the server, which, in it's turn will send the file back to the client.

Comment: The key value … being part of a URI. So you still have a URI, you just have hoops to leap though (and you provide the code to do the hoop leaping to the client).

Comment: You can forget about trying to do anything sane with a Word document in a response to a request from an XHR object though.

Comment: OK, so my option is adding a layer of authentication + authorization. Where do I begin?

Comment: First pick a method to authenticate your users (ip, password, SSL client cert, etc). Then … it depends on which method you use.

Comment: The users are already authenticated and logged in to the site (it's a WordPress site). So only they will get the link. But - if they pass the link along to a non-user or it leaks out another way, anyone will be able to use it. So how do I protect it?

Comment: @teletoh — Then check they are logged in before serving up the document.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked "Enter" before finishing the comment. Please read it again, now edited.

Comment: @teletoh — Check they are logged in **before serving up the document** (as well as before serving up the link).

Comment: I see. How do I do that? Let's assume the link has leaked out and anyone can use it. How do I interfere with the process of 'click a link->the file is served'?

Comment: The link goes to a PHP script. The PHP script checks the authentication. If it passes it serves up a Word document. If it fails it serves up an HTTP error code and a login page. i.e. the same as any other page, except the response is a Word document instead of an HTML document.

Comment: Since I'm using WordPress this whole process is automatic. Do you know how to interfere with the process with WP?

Comment: No. I've never needed to hack it. You just need to write a PHP script that makes use of its auth API though.

Comment: OK. I'll look into it. Thanks for clearing the situation up for me. I wish you wrote an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: I did write an answer, we've been commenting on it.

Comment: Right. You got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can add links to uploaded media in WordPress easily. Just remember to link to the actual file:

[image: insert media in wordpress]

Comment: can I limit the users to specific file types?
Can I manipulate the fields shown in your example? For instance, change the label "Description" to something else?
And how can I limit them to only open the file as read only?

Comment: Um, if you have a WordPress site, why don't you just try it out and see? I'm not sure you can limit what kind of files users (who can write articles) can upload. But if you have users writing on your site who you do not trust, I'd say you have bigger problems.  The users who just read your articles can of course just download whatever is made available to them. If you save the word file as read only before you upload it, I think it will be read only when they open it as well. But it doesn't really matter if it's read only or not as they won't be touching the version on your site.

Comment: My users won't be able to write anything except for in input fields and for uploading files. So far WP has been too limiting for most of my needs so I'm doing most stuff with PHP and JS but I will look into your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, redirect the browser to the location of the file. It's depend on user's browser settings that file opens on the browser directly, or user sees open/save dialog.

But, if you want to open the file inside the browser without letting user download it, you should redirect her/him to a custom page. e.g. a page that loads a doc editor.

There's no way to show a Microsoft Word file inside the browser unless they install proper software. e.g. an Applet or ActiveX or something that be able to open MSWord files.

Comment: Be careful with the ambiguous use of the word "standard". Microsoft Word file __is__ standard (albeit several different standards for different versions of MS Word)! What is a problem is that MS Word may not be installed on every user's PC, so those users will not be able to view the file. Don't rely on a PDF viewer being installed either, it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @Mark Baker, thanks. With my type of users I can safely assume they have MS Word installed.

Comment: @teletoh: By opening/downloading the file, they cannot edit the file on the server directly. So, it's safe from that point.

Comment: No … but if you are opening it over HTTP, then it will be copied to a temporary location and any changes will be lost without a SaveAs. Clients can't write to a web server (unless the client and server specifically support HTTP PUT requests)

Comment: @Quentin, so if the link URL is `www.something.com/file.doc` and the user clicks on it, than if they have the MS plugin it will open in their browser and if not than it will be opened in MS Word?

Comment: @teletoh — It really depends on how the system is configured. On most of mine (for example), it would be saved to my downloads folder and then opened in OO.o if I were to click it.

Comment: @Quentin, OK, I just wanted to be sure the user will eventually read the file, regardless of his configuration.

Comment: Now that I think of it, this isn't the right solution for me because with this solution anyone can watch the files and search engines can index it.
I need only specific users to be able to watch the files so I need to send the file from the server to the client and not just give them the link.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [WP Client File Share](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-client-file-share/) plugin.

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I need but you're first answer did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I just realized I can't use your solution. Please see my edit to the question and I'd love to read your thoughts.